# Memory Leak and OutOfMemoryException - Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, weak-references, jvisualvm

I am currently working a Standalone Java Swing application, which is quite a complex one with lot of labels and input text fields.
What I found is, after each operation the memory consumption of the application as in Windows Task manager is increasing atleast by 2 MB. Upon reaching to a total memory consumption of ~305 MB, the application crashes with Out of Memory Exception.
I explicitly mentioned for garbage collection in the event handler, but it didn't made any good.
I profiled the application with JVisualVM. I found few of my classes have a memory graph of an increment slope which never comes down.
[image: Memory Usage graph for class InspectableInputTextImpl]

But for other classes the graph is quite normal like a wave pattern, as below image:
[image: Memory Usage graph for class char array]

From above chart I came to conclusion that memory leak is happening for InspectableInputTextImpl class. To fix I added weakReference instantiation for the said class like below:

```
InspectableInputTextImpl inputText = new InspectableInputTextImpl(screen, componentId, length);
        WeakReference<InspectableInputTextImpl> weakInputText = new WeakReference<InspectableInputTextImpl>(inputText);
        ((TInputText) weakInputText.get()).setCustomDocument(new TRestrict4InputTextDocument());
        ((TInputText) weakInputText.get()).setMaxLength(maxLength);
        ((TInputText) weakInputText.get()).setRequirement(required);
```

Even this also didn't improved anything, still the memory chart looks exactly same.
Below are my questions:

1. Am I correct on the conclusion that InspectableInputTextImpl itself
   is causing the memory leak based on the chart?
2. If I am correct could you share with your thoughts on fixing the
   issue. Will converting the instance to a singleton will fix it?

Comment: The JVM will usually not bother GC until it is getting close to an `OutOfMemeoryError`. If no OOME is seen, no memory leak is proven.

Comment: Upon reaching a memory ~305 MB, the application crashes with OOME. At that time also the graph of mentioned class is not coming down, I hope gc is having no impact on that class.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest analysing a heap dump to verify the cause of memory leak. You can start your application with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError VM option and it will create a .hprof file with a dump of the heap at the point it crashes. Then you can use a tool like [Eclipse MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to have a look at the dump. It may verify your suspicion about InspectableInputTextImpl or give you a different clue.

You can take on how to fix the problem (your question 2) after you verify what exactly is the problem (your question 1).